# AS number look up

Tags: ip

I have a list of thousands of urls, for each host in these URLs I want to get their AS "Autonomous System" number. What is the best way to do that automatically?

I have seen some websites that provide manual ASN look up by the company name, but what I'm looking for is 1) an API or a command line to send look up requests automatically, 2) the look up should be based on the host not on the company name.

Thank you

Comment: unfortunately, this is not an InfoSec question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPasn - https://github.com/In7rud3R/IPasn

This tool uses Cymrus tool and provides a command line interface to turn IPs and hostnames into geo and ASN data.

It even accepts a text file as input. Simply create input.txt in your current directory and run ipasn.py.

Comment: Thank you bizarrechaos. That's exactly what I'm looking for